# iPhone Login -> tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiview, authentication, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created an app and a login and would like to join them together with no luck. The app has a tabbarcontroller with navigationcontrollers via tableviewcells to drill down to other views of the app.

As I am having no luck in joining the two. I have tried to build on from the login that I have done. I can push to a new view but it does not show a tabbarcontroller etc on the next view. I have seen various forums with people having this problem as well.

So, my question: How can I make a new page (login) open to a TabBarController instead of a view (in the middle of my app, not at the launch)?

Does anyone out there know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use navigation controller in tab bar controller. lets say the navigation controller is its first view controller. Now when the root view controller of the navigation is being displayed, you can see the tab bar. Now if you keep pushing new view controllers in this navigation controller, the tab bar wont hide itself.

However if you present some view controller modally, it would hide itself.

As far as login is concerned, i will check if user has logged in or not. if no, then i would set the root view controller of navigation controller as loginviewconroller else some home page.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the if the user is logged in in the first viewController that get loaded.

From there I would present the loginViewController via the presentModalViewController method.
The use will not see the tabbar if you set the withAnimation:NO.

Now just dismiss the login viewcontroller when the use is logged in.

One could also send a notification that the is logged in, so that viewcontrollers can update them self for the no logged in user.

Comment: Hey man, what do you mean by, "One could also send a notification that the is logged in, so that viewcontrollers can update them self for the no logged in user."? Thanks.

Comment: A UINotification, lookup the NSNotificationCenter.